# At google cloud monitoring Set up quota usage alerts is free?

Tags: google-cloud-monitoring

I'm using youtube data API at Google Cloud Console.

I want to send slack to my channel if it's quota exceed 90% of quota limit per day. (900)
By setting Alert policy at Monitoring Tab

I want to know setting an alert policy and sending alert is free or paid?

At some Google monitoring document it costs by metric but I'm confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up an alert policy and sending alerts using Google Cloud Monitoring is **free**. As confirmed in the documentation for both [metric-based](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts#limits) & [log-based alerting policies](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/alerting/monitoring-logs#limits), there are no costs associated with using alerting policies.

Cost might come from the use of notification channels such as pub/sub notification channels. For example, Custom metrics are charged based on the number of data points collected. Check [Chargeable metrics](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing#metrics-chargeable) and [Cloud Monitoring pricing summary](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing#monitoring-pricing-summary) for more information.

In addition to that, writing a metric produces costs If it's a custom metric. [Standard metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp) are free of charge.

If you want to know how much a metric costs you basically have to calculate from the price, most likely with [Google Cloud pricing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator).

Important is how often the metrics get written. One example for 2000 custom metrics:

once a minute = 134 Dollar

every 30 sec = 306 Dollar

every 5 sec = 2030 Dollar

Comment: thank you for your kind comment! I want to ask that when I create alert for quota at API usage tab using metric serviceruntime.googleapis.com/quota/rate/net_usage metric. and it's non-chargable metric so it doesn't cost right?

Comment: That's correct. Since you are using a non-chargable metric (serviceruntime.googleapis.com/quota/rate/net\_usage) provided by Google Cloud Monitoring to setup your alert for quota usage, there should be no additional cost associated with this specific alert setup.

Answer (score 0):

**for gist understanding**

setting an alert policy and sending alerts in google cloud monitoring as of now is a free feature.and so you can use it to send alert but there may be costs associated with the usage of the YouTube Data API itself follow [youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) and if you you are using stackdriver then please tack a look at [stackdriver/pricing](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing)

to understand the pricing please try to understand information given below also follow the given refs. for better details

> **Cloud Monitoring**
>
> Monitoring charges for the following:
>
> Metrics measured by bytes ingested, when the ingested metric data
> exceeds the free monthly metric allotment.
>
> *Non-chargeable metrics don't count towards the allotment limit.
>
> *Metrics measured by number of samples ingested.
>
> *Cloud Monitoring API read calls that exceed the free monthly API   allotment.
>
> *Monitoring API write calls don't count towards the allotment limit.
>
> *Execution of uptime checks.
>
> *Execution of synthetic monitors.

also understand these

> **Non-chargeable metrics**
>
> Metric data from Google Cloud, GKE Enterprise, and Knative isn't
> chargeable. Non-chargeable (free) metrics include the following:
>
> Google Cloud metrics. For additional information, see Footnote 2.
>
> GKE Enterprise metrics. For additional information, see Footnote 2.
>
> Istio metrics
>
> Knative metrics
>
> Google Kubernetes Engine system metrics
>
> gent.googleapis.com/agent/ metrics

> **Chargeable metrics**
>
> All metric data, except for those metrics listed in the section titled
> Non-chargeable metrics, is chargeable. Most metric ingestion is
> charged by the number of bytes, but some is charged by the number of
> samples; these pricing models are described in the following sections.
>
> The following factors contribute to ingestion costs:
>
> The type of data points—scalar values or distribution values—collected by the metrics.
> For information about the data type associated with a specific metric type, see the list of metrics.
> For information about scalar and distribution data types, see Value types.
>
> The number of data points written to time series. This value depends on the frequency with which the data is sampled and the
> cardinality of your data. The cardinality determines how many time
> series are generated for a combination of metric and
> monitored-resource types; for more information, see Cardinality.
>
> The values for the metric and resource labels that are part of your
> time series don't contribute to your charges.

for more follow [pricing#metrics-non-chargeable](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing#metrics-non-chargeable)
also

Comment: thank you for your kind comment! I want to ask that when I create alert for quota at API usage tab using metric serviceruntime.googleapis.com/quota/rate/net_usage metric. and it's non-chargable metric so it doesn't cost right?

Comment: fetch consumer_quota|filter resource.project_id=='projectid'|{metric serviceruntime.googleapis.com/quota/rate/net_usage|filter metric.quota_metric=='youtube.googleapis.com/default'|map add [metric.limit_name: 'defaultPerMinutePerProject']|align delta_gauge(1m)|group_by [resource.project_id,resource.service,metric.quota_metric,metric.limit_name],sum(value.net_usage);metric serviceruntime.googleapis.com/quota/limit|filter metric.quota_metric=='youtube.googleapis.com/default'&&metric.limit_name=='defaultPerMinutePerProject'

Comment: |group_by [resource.project_id,resource.service,metric.quota_metric,metric.limit_name],sliding(1m),.min}|ratio|every 30s|condition gt(val(), 0.8 '1')